# json serializer with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, java-custom-serialization

I have **BigDecimalSerializer**

```
public class BigDecimalSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {

@Override
public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
  throws IOException {
gen.writeString(value.setScale(6, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString());
}
}
```

and then

```
 @JsonSerialize(using = BigDecimalSerializer.class)
 private BigDecimal foo;
```

is there any way that instead of doing annotate in each member variable, I tell the spring boot at once that apply to all project ?

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring the `ObjectMapper` by adding a custom module. In case you're using `spring-data-rest` this can look like this:

```
@Configuration
public static class ObjectMapperConfigurer extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureJacksonObjectMapper(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        SimpleModule myModule = new SimpleModule();
        myModule.addSerializer(BigDecimal.class, BigDecimalSerializer.class);           
        objectMapper.registerModule(myModule));
    }
}
```

Otherwise simply provide your own `ObjectMapper` bean and configure it on creation.

Comment: `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` is depricated